# Use an irregularly spaced, non-categorical axis on a categorical plot in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6, seaborn

I'm creating a violin plot in Seaborn, which by default, assumes that the x-axis is categorical, and therefore evenly spaces the data, rather than scaling it by a value. I would like the spacing between the individual violins to be defined by values associated with each violin, rather than just spacing them evenly. I have read a number of things suggesting that I can overwrite the defaults with matplotlib commands, but can't get anything to work.

```
sns.set(palette='muted', color_codes=True)
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8,5))
sns.violinplot(x = lsdf['6MO_CUM_MBO/1000FT'], y = lsdf.RELATIVE_DEPTH,
data=lsdf, palette="Blues", ax=axes[0,0])
```

I think the key issue here, is I'm not exactly sure what Seaborn's defaults are controling. Do I need to modify the axes object created by subplots? or the ax=[0,0] object?

The only answer I found to a similar question had a solution which was just, "do it in matplotlib," but I need the plots available in seaborn. Thanks for your help.

[image: seaborn categorical violin plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I eventually solved this, sort of... I caved and used pure matplotlib, gave up on Seaborn. The matplotlib violinplot takes an array-like `positions` argument which when passed numeric values, auto-scales the x-axis and behaves exactly as `plt.plot` or any plot where marker position and axis range are derived from the input data. I still used `seaborn.set()` to get the nice Seaborn aesthetic. There is matplotlib violin plot customization [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/customized_violin.html) which has nice examples of how to edit the details of the violins which allowed me to customize the violins and mimic all parts of the Seaborn violin plot.

Comment: Thank you for the effort of answering your own question. Would you be willing to also share the code (even if it is incomplete)?